# TCP Checksum Calculation Changing - tcp offloading is disabled

Tags: c, linux, tcp, checksum, netfilter

I am manipulating TCP packets using netfilter, so I have to recalculate the TCP and IP checksums which is working as expected.

Wireshark reports the checksums are correct on the way out of the server (which matches what the client thinks they should be as well), but when they reach the client the checksum is always replaced with 0xAA6A.

In the post routing hook, I am calculating the TCP checksum as follows... after manipulating the addresses/ports.

```
 tcp_header->check = 0;
 tcp_header->check = tcp_v4_check(tcp_len,
   ip_header->saddr,
   ip_header->daddr,
   csum_partial((char *)tcp_header, tcp_len, 0));
```

The IP checksum is fine using

```
 ip_send_check(ip_header);
```

The server does not have TCP offloading enabled for RX or TX and also does not even support it, I get an unsupported error when attempting to enable or disable.

```
Offload parameters for eth0:
rx-checksumming: off
tx-checksumming: off
scatter-gather: off
tcp-segmentation-offload: off
udp-fragmentation-offload: off
generic-segmentation-offload: off
generic-receive-offload: on
large-receive-offload: off
rx-vlan-offload: off
tx-vlan-offload: off
ntuple-filters: off
receive-hashing: off
```

Another related point that I am not to sure on... I also manipulate packets/ports in a pre-routing hook on the server, and they are accepted by the transport layer and are definitely getting to my application no matter what I seem to do to the TCP checksum, I was under the assumption that they would be dropped if the TCP checksum wasn't updated after a change of IP Address/ and Port.

Is there any obvious reason for this behaviour or am I misunderstanding part of the network stack?

**Update:**

Setting ip_summed to CHECKSUM_NONE is stopping the checksum being recalculated once it leaves my code. What I'm not sure about is why it is being re-calculated to an incorrect fixed value? If I don't set it, it is set to CHECKSUM_PARTIAL.

Answer (score 1):

If the value is always the same on the other side, I see 2 main possibilities: 1) you  overwrite the checksum later after this code 2) tcp_len is wrong
You should also check if NETIF_F_V4_CSUM is set in the sockbuff dev->features because the kernel does something different in this case

Comment: The checksum isn't overwritten in my code at least, and tcp_len should be right as I am actually getting the correct checksum until it  leaves the netfilter postrouting hook (also seen by Wireshark). I will take a look at NETIF_F_V4_CSUM. Setting skb->ip_summed to CHECKSUM_NONE seems to work, ideally it is only a temporary fix as offloading would be beneficial. I'm assuming  offloading uses the ip addresses from the packet for the TCP psuedo header?

Comment: what was the value before you set it to CHECKSUM_NONE?
When you say "it works", what do you see on the wire for the checksum after setting to NONE? (or are you seeing 0)
Offloading in linux vanilla does not do much besides checksumming on the send side but anyway your patch would need to work no matter what.

Comment: When I set ip_summed to CHECKSUM_NONE, the TCP checksum is correct when it leaves my netfilter hook (as before), and is also correct when it gets to the client (which it wasn't before). I will update the question with some more information.

Comment: I cannot try myself but I *think* that by setting ip_summed to CHECKSUM_NONE, you basically ask the TCP code to redo the checksum.  Did you try to set a bogus value in check and leave ip_summed to CHECKSUM_NONE?  If I am correct, it should work just as well.

That's why I was asking you what is the value ip_summed before your code changes it.  I believe the partial checksumming you're doing in your code will work only if it is CHECKSUM_PARTIAL